# How do I make an error handler with flask

Tags: flask

I am creating a web application and I would like to do a styled 404 page not found if someone tries to enter one of my routes that is not created. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a error handler of any error code in flask you must do the following, for my example I will use a `404` error as requested in the post:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

If you want to error handle a `505` just substitut the `404` for a `505` and create a new html file in templates